# Perforce how save changelist number when created in command line?

Tags: perforce

```
p4 --field "Description=My pending change" --field "Files=" change -o | p4 change -i
```

When I call that , it created a new changelist and output : "Change 35837 created".

So how can I save this changeList number "35837" to variable?

I need save number to do some , bucause I using bat file.

Comment: You need to save the number to do what?

Comment: @SamStafford I want to add file to changelist like this `p4 edit fileName -c changelist`

Comment: ah -- I'll add that to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to open a file in a numbered changelist within a simple script, you can just take advantage of the default changelist and the fact that a new numbered changelist will take ownership of files in the default changelist by default.

```
p4 edit fileName
p4 --field "Description=derp" change -o | p4 change -i
```

If your very next step is going to be to modify that file and submit that numbered changelist, skip the intermediate step of creating a pending numbered changelist; `submit` will do that part for you automatically.

```
p4 edit fileName
echo derp>>fileName
p4 submit -d "derp" fileName
```

When you create a changelist, it's saved on the server.  Run:

```
p4 changes -m1
```

to see the changelist that you just created.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite late to the party, but here's what I did within my DOS script:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims= " %%i in ('p4 change') do set CHANGE_NUMBER_P4=%%i
```

If you need this to work on the command line, use a single % instead, as in

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims= " %i in ('p4 change') do set CHANGE_NUMBER_P4=%i
```

Check `echo %CHANGE_NUMBER_P4%` (provided you saved the changelist).

We're parsing the second token delimited by a whitespace.